# Data Validation for Swagger

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, swagger

I'm trying to simplify endpoint data validation for a flask application, with a [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) endpoint spec. I've avoided using the entire swagger-generated server code, because I find [connexion](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/connexion) too opaque. Instead I use the model objects generated by Swagger, but write the controllers myself. For example, this is the endpoint for searching for restaurants nearby. The user needs to provide either a `zip_code` or a combination `latitude` and `longitude`, and those values need to be validated:

```
from flask import jsonify, request, Response
from models import RestaurantSearchRequest, RestaurantSearchResponse

app_blueprint = Blueprint(__name__, __name__, url_prefix='/restaurants')

@app_blueprint.route(
    utils.versioned_api_route('/search/'), methods=['GET'])
def find_restaurants_by_zip_or_lat_lng() -> Response:
    request_data = utils.multidict_to_dict(request.args)

    try:
        search_request = RestaurantSearchRequest.from_dict(request_data)
        search_response = RestaurantSearchResponse.from_lat_lng_zip(**search_request.to_dict())

        return Response(jsonify(search_response.to_dict()), 200)

    except ValueError as ex:
        return Response(ex.message, 400)
```

Right now the data validation is being done in the model using [Voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous), but it requires a lot of boilerplate:

```
from voluptuous.schema_builder import Schema

from lib import validators
from models.swagger import RestaurantSearchRequest as SwaggerRestaurantSearchRequest

# Inherit all swagger utils, such as `to_dict` and `from_dict`
class RestaurantSearchRequest(SwaggerRestaurantSearchRequest):
    def __init__(self: 'RestaurantSearchRequest', latitude: float=None, longitude: float=None, zip_code: str=None):

    schema = Schema({
        'zip_code': validators.validate_zip_code,
        'latitude': validators.validate_latitude,
        'longitude': validators.validate_longitude,
    })

    schema({
        'zip_code': zip_code,
        'latitude': latitude,
        'longitude': longitude,
    })

    super(RestaurantSearchRequest, self).__init__(latitude, longitude, zip_code)

    if (self.longitude is None or self.latitude is None) and self.zip_code is None:
        raise ValueError('Must provide either zip code or lat/lng')
```

I'd also like to get the logic out of the model and move it to a decorator in the view function. The key to all of this is having to the flexability to validate individual fields, as well validate the combination of fields, like above.

Are there any existing libraries out there I can leverage, or is there generic validator that I can use for something like this?